# ntp date not showing the correct time

Tags: server, iptables, ntp

I was having an issue in which the time my ubuntu machine was showing is 5 hours ahead of my standard time. So I installed ntpd for that using

```
apt-get install ntp
```

after that I restarted ntp but still my time is 5 hours ahead of my standard time in India. Please Help.

Comment: What does the `mtop` has to do with `ntp`? Is this a result of an earlier attempt to install `mtop`? I don't see anything about that in your question.

Comment: I know mtop does't has to do anything with ntp. I was trying to install ntp not mtop.

Comment: Okay, then I think it is a duplicate of [Unable to synchronize time using NTP](http://askubuntu.com/q/244526/88802)

Comment: No I tried that approach gives the error #service ntp stop then, #ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com 22 Jul 19:30:31 ntpdate[29701]: no server suitable for synchronization found

Comment: Well, have you tried another server besides `ntp.ubuntu.com`? It may be down for you or too far geographically so it disregards that as suitable. Try `pool.ntp.org` or `<country-tld>.pool.ntp.org` (e.g. `nl.pool.ntp.org`). And do you have a working internet connection accepting outbound NTP traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command update your date and time :)

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
22 Jul 19:11:53 ntpdate[29585]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting

Comment: service ntpd stop;
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com

Comment: service ntpd stop
ntpd: unrecognized service

Comment: @Tarun See [Unable to synchronize time using NTP](http://askubuntu.com/q/244526/88802)

Comment: I tried it #service ntp stop then, #ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
22 Jul 19:30:31 ntpdate[29701]: no server suitable for synchronization found

Comment: I found the solution to my problem the port number 123 which is used by ntp was not open. Now everything is smooth.

Comment: @Tarun: How do you check if the port is open/closed?